# Custom validation rule in CakePHP not working as intended

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

I wrote a custom validation method inside my Submission model that basically allows a blank input field, but once someone enters something in it, it'll validate the data entered.

The validation inside my Submission Model looks like this (All other validation rules are working except for 'description'):

```
    var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Please enter a title'
        ),
        'minLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 5),
            'message' => 'Please make your title longer'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 300),
            'message' => 'Your title needs to be shorter'
        ),
    ),
    'description' => array(
        'checkDescription' => array(
            'rule' => array('validateDescription'),
            'message' => 'Description must be greater than 5 characters'
        ),
    ),
    'source' => array(
        'source' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Enter a valid source URL'
        ),
        'website' => array(
            'rule' => 'url',
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid source URL'
        ),
    )
);
```

My method which is also in my Submission model (below the above code) is:

```
    public function validateDescription($data) {
    if(empty($data['Submission']['description']))
        return true;

    if((strlen($data['Submission']['description'])) <= 5)
        return false;
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working at all. In my view, I've got this to display the error:

```
    if ($form->isFieldError('Submission.description'))
    echo ($form->error('Submission.description', null, array('class' => 'error')));
```

The only reason I'm trying to do this, is because using the normal validation with `required => false` and `allowEmpty => true` along with a `minLength` and `maxLength` validation rule weren't behaving how I intended.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$data` variable passed into the validation method only contains `array($fieldname => $value)`. You're also not returning `true` for strings over length of 5. Your method should look like this:

```
public function validateDescription(array $data) {
    $value = current($data);
    return !$value || strlen($value) > 5;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! If I were to add another validation rule to that, how would you suggest that I send a custom 'message' back to the 'description' array within the $validate property? I was thinking of maybe doing 3 conditionals and changing the $message = 'needs to be greater than 5 characters' or $message = 'needs to be less than 10k chars' and returning that.

Comment: I'd either combine that into one message ("Needs to be between x and y") or make it separate rules that each have their own message.

Comment: also note that you are missing the crucial "last"=>true part